# How would I go about moving an object to another when its hovered over?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have absolutely no way of knowing how to word this properly. But I am trying to create a menu with a highlighter. Upon Hovering an option the highlighter moves to whichever option is hovered over and stays there until the next option is covered over.

````
   {
       SelectionBackground.transform.position.y = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position.y, gameObject, Time.deltaTime * speed);
   }
       ```
````

Comment: [`IPointerHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html) is most likely what you're looking for. You'll know when an object is hovered, then you just need to convert the screen space position to whatever coordinate slace your object is in and move it there.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`IPointerEnterHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html) interface you could do something like e.g.

```
// This goes onto your highlighter object
public class Highlighter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Target;

    public float speed = 1;
    public Vector3 offset;

    private void Update ()
    {
        if(!Target) return;
        
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Target.position + offset, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

And then on each object have

```
public class Option : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private Highlighter _highlighter;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        if(!_highlighter) _highlighter = FindObjectOfType<Highlighter>();
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        if(!_highlighter) _highlighter = FindObjectOfType<Highlighter>();
        
        _highlighter.Target = transform;
    }
}
```